# Stone-Cech Compactification of the real line

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactifications, stone-cech-compactification

I have a question in $\beta\mathbb{R}$, the Stone-Cech compactification of the real line $\mathbb{R}$. My question is: is $\beta\mathbb{R}$ a $\mathrm{F}$-space, i.e., the closure of two disjoint open $F_{\sigma}$-sets are disjoint? I know that $\beta\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathrm{F}$-space, but not if the whole space has this property.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: This is not a vector space. Could you provide a correct link for F-space? And Fréchet space only makes sense for vector space, so this sounds senseless.

Comment: Or perhaps you mean the meaning of F-space as the one used in Alan Dow's paper *Some set-theory, Stone–Čech, and F-spaces* https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2011.06.007 and some other related papers cited there?

Comment: @MartinSleziak : I edited my definition of an F-space sorry for that.

Comment: Perhaps you could add at least some reference to the fact that the Stone-Čech remainder is an F-space - I'd guess that the paper by Gillman and Henriksen: *Rings of continuous functions in which every finitely generated ideal is principal* https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1956-0078980-4 seems like a reasonable candidate - and I suppose that after that we can delete all comments related to clarification of the question.

Comment: And since I see you have posted from an unregistered account, I will also mention that registering might be useful if you want to prevent the possibility that you lose access to your post in the future. More details on this can be found here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/unregistered-users/info

Comment: Yes Gillman and Hendriksen is the right reference for this. One can also prove that the closure of every open $F_{\sigma}$-set is open (this property is also known under $\sigma$-Stonean if I am right. This would imply that we have a F-space.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, essentially because $\mathbb{R}$ embeds as a locally compact open subspace of $\beta\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}$ is not an F-space.

In detail, for the purposes of this answer I will write $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \beta\mathbb{R}$. The facts we will use are that $\mathbb{R}$ is an open subspace of $\beta\mathbb{R}$ because it is locally compact, and that compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are compact, and therefore closed, in $\beta\mathbb{R}$.

Consider $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. These are disjoint opens in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore in $\beta\mathbb{R}$ (because $\mathbb{R}$ is an open subset). The first set $(0,1) = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty [2^{-i},1-2^{-i}]$, so is $F_\sigma$ in $\beta\mathbb{R}$ (because closed bounded intervals are compact in $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore closed in $\beta\mathbb{R}$). A similar argument shows that $(1,2)$ is $F_\sigma$. Their closures are $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and as these are compact, they are also their closures in $\beta\mathbb{R}$. These are not disjoint.